Download p5.js sketch canvas as PDF using jsPDF addImage JPEG
Trying to get a minimal script running to download a p5.js sketch canvas element as a PDF using jsPDF -- specifically the jsPDF addImage method, after converting the canvas to a JPEG using the JS toDataURL method.
I can get p5.js to draw on the canvas and jsPDF to download a PDF after launching the page, but the PDF is blank (black with JPEG, white with PNG, presumably b/c alpha channel). I'm guessing this is because of where I have the jsPDF code in the script, but anywhere else I put it, the download doesn't work.
Any advice?
(FWIW, I tried the solution to this: JsPDF addImage jpeg background is black, but I just end up with an all-white PDF, like when I go with PNG instead of JPEG)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Page 0</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="page0.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

function  setup() {

  let     the_canvas  =     createCanvas(792, 612, P2D);

                            noLoop();

  let     doc         = new jsPDF("l", "pt", [792, 612]);

  let     the_img     =     the_canvas.elt.toDataURL("image/JPEG", 1.0);
                            doc.addImage(the_img, "JPEG", 0, 0, 792, 612);

                            doc.save("page0.pdf");
                          
}

function  draw() {

                            background(43);

                            stroke(200);
                            fill(200);
                            textSize(100);
                            text("Test", 500, 500);

}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}


Since setup runs first, then draw, you save the PDF before writing text to it.
Try drawing and writing, then saving the PDF as the final step:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Page 0</title>
<style>
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js"
  integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
let canvas;

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(792, 612, P2D);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(43);
  stroke(200);
  fill(200);
  textSize(100);
  text("Test", 500, 500);
  const doc = new jsPDF("l", "pt", [792, 612]);
  const img = canvas.elt.toDataURL("image/JPEG", 1.0);
  doc.addImage(img, "JPEG", 0, 0, 792, 612);
  doc.save("page0.pdf");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Note that separating setup and draw functions as shown above isn't strictly necessary since you're doing a one-shot operation. You could put all of the code in setup, or all of the code in draw (with noLoop() so it only runs once).

Thanks! This works in the p5.js web editor. I tried this update in my local env, with the same file breakout as my original post, and it still wasn't working. So there's something for me to figure out with my env, but at least I have this solution as a model now. Much appreciated.

FWIW, worked in my local env when I combined the setup() and draw() functions.

That shouldn't be necessary. There must be some problem with your local environment, like an outdated p5 version or something like that. I ran this exact code locally on Ubuntu 22.04 and Firefox and it worked fine.

Hmm, I'll keep investigating. Looks like I'm on 1.9.0 as well, but I am using a VS Code extension specific to p5. I also had to keep the first function named setup() for it to run, which probably also isn't necessary.

setup and draw are special functions that p5 calls for you when it loads, after populating the global variables. So you can't rename them, but since you're using noLoop(), it doesn't matter which (or both) of the functions the code is in, as long as the order of drawing, then PDFing, is correct.
